# What page is being loaded by Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm tasked to execute specific page javascript on pagechange in Jquery Mobile (Such as geolocate the user on one page or show a Google map on another page)

Its really not clear how to execute javascript after a pagechange but i'm almost there, i was able to use

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function(event){

    loadGmaps();
    geolocate();

});
```

But the problem is that this code executes on each page change/page init and if i'm not on a page that has a #map tag, it just executes code for nothing. Worst? Jquery keeps pages loaded in memory but hides them. So if i change page, it can reload the map 16 times in a row for nothing.

I'm really confused as to how you are supposed to bind specific page javascript in a jquery mobile loaded page. I'm lurked all around the web and i'm sure i'm not the only one looking for that specific trick...

Thanks

---

**EDIT**

I changed my code to reflect Jasper's solution, and it works fine except for the geolocation:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#wp-post-id-70', function(event){
    geolocate();
});
$(document).on('pageinit', '.wp-post-type-spa', function(event){
    loadGmaps();
});
```

The maps load fine on each page i visit that is a spa, but when i load a spa page from a fresh load, if i click on the logo to go back to the home page, it loads the home page and then fires the "geolocate" function but nothing happens in terms of geolocation:

```
function geolocate()
{
    if (navigator.geolocation) { 
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            function(position){
                $('#near_spa').load('?latitude='+position.coords.latitude.toString()+'& longitude='+position.coords.longitude.toString()+' #near_spa > *');
            }
        );
    }else{ 
        alert('Votre navigateur ne supporte pas la géolocalisation ou refuse l\'accès aux données de localisation');
    }
}
```

The code really goes up to the navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition, it gets called but then pffff, nothing. If i reload the home page manually with F5, i now get the geolocation request...

---

**EDIT**

Never mind that "map" loads fine on each page, it doesn't anymore, probably me and my brain being too tired...

Therefore, the

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '.wp-post-type-spa', function(event){
    loadGmaps();
});
```

Doesn't load the maps anymore at all and yes, i verified, the pages do feature a wp-post-type-spa class...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have code that only runs once per pseudo-page, then use the `pageinit` event, which only runs once every time a pseudo-page is added to the DOM.

You can also target specific pseudo-pages in your `bind` call:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#some-map-page', function(event){

    loadGmaps();
    geolocate();

});
```

This will only run when the `pageinit` event fires on an element with the ID of `some-map-page`. You could for example add a class to each pseudo-page element where you want to run the map code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="some-map-page" class="map-page">...</div>
```

Which would work with the following event binding:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '.map-page', function(event){

    loadGmaps();
    geolocate();

});
```

Notice that I'm using `.on()` as a delegated event handler, which is very useful when using jQuery Mobile as you can't ever be sure when a pseudo-page exists in the DOM.

Comment: Should the pageinit be inside the <div data-role="page">? My integrator asked me to put it in the footer so it's outside the div for now

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin It can live wherever. I suggest placing all this type of JS in a central include file, then including that file on each HTML document. That way the code will always be available no matter how the user entered your site.

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin I'd have to take a look at your site to really help. But make sure that you aren't using IDs where that element can exist on more than one pseudo-page at a time, it will make it seem as though nothing is happening but in reality the wrong element is being selected.

Comment: Nahh everything all right for the Ids at least, each data-role=page has an id of "wp-post-id-xyz" matching the post id in wordpress and as far as i know, i can reuse classes, so why isn't the ".wp-post-type-spa" firing off?

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin I can give some more specific feedback if you post a URL to the site. Especially with a WordPress site there are just too many possible issues to go through all of them blindly.

Comment: We'll finish the site and live with the problems till then, it's due friday, so i'll post the public staging url at that point so you can look at it. Worst comes works, we'll remove Jquery mobile (it's mainly for the seamless transitions that we use it)